# Adding Content Inside a HTML Tag with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a tag that looks like this:

```
<input name="code" type="text" />
```

I wish to leverage JQuery to add text inside this tag e.g.

```
<input name="code" type="text" data-hj-whitelist />
```

The reason for this is Hotjar whitelisting with the data-hj-whitelist addition.

This is my current code, which I am aware will not work as I'm adding a class of which data-hj-whitelist is not. Other functions that sprung to mind e.g. add, append etc, add after the tag is closed. I need to add text inside the tag itself.

```
//WordPress Format
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    //Obviously won't work as I'm not adding a class
    $('input').addClass('colin');
    //Console log to know the script fired  
    console.log('fired');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do just:

```
$('input[name="code"]').attr('data-hj-whitelist','')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to add a data attribute to an input. You may do so like this:

```
$('input[name="code"]').attr("data-hj-whitelist","");
```

If needed, you may retrieve the value of a data attribute like this:

```
// Notice that the data- prefix is removed
$('input[name="code"]').data("hj-whitelist");

// You may also get the value using attr()
$('input[name="code"]').attr("data-hj-whitelist");
```

---

**Example**

```js
// Set with attr(), retrieve with attr()
$('input[name="code"]').attr("data-hj-whitelist", "foo1")
console.log($('input[name="code"]').attr("data-hj-whitelist"));

// Set with attr(), retrieve with data()
$('input[name="code"]').attr("data-hj-whitelist", "foo2")
console.log($('input[name="code"]').data("hj-whitelist"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="code" type="text" />
```

Comment: For real? Drive-by down vote for the correct answer?

Comment: What's the logic in downvoting this answer and upvoting mine?

Comment: Thank you for both your input, appreciated it.